# special compare in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm trying to achieve this:

```
for i=1:maxaps
    for j=1:length(num2)
        **if (isequal(sortedCell(i),txt2(j)) && sortedCell(i)~=0)** %important line
            rssi2sorted(i)=rssi2(j); %I don't think we need matching part
        break;
        end
    end
end
```

and I receive this error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'ne'
for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> sortingmethod at 116
        if
        (isequal(sortedCell(i),txt2(j))
        && sortedCell(i)~=0)
```

if I try like this:

```
for i=1:maxaps
    for j=1:length(num2)
        **if (isequal(sortedCell{i},txt2(j)) && sortedCell(i)~=0)** %important line
            rssi2sorted(i)=rssi2(j); %I don't think we need matching part
        break;
        end
    end
end
```

the elements can't be compared because of the format:

```
>> sortedCell{1}

ans =

00:1e:58:f4:15:f7

>> txt2(6)

ans = 

    '00:1e:58:f4:15:f7'
```

any recommendations on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying this: `~isempty(sortedCell(i))` when you write `sortedCell(i)~=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue is actually with this part (the [`ne`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ne.html) that your error refers to):

```
sortedCell(i)~=0
```

You're comparing a cell, rather than its contents, to zero. You should use:

```
sortedCell{i}~=0
```

*EDIT*:

If the question is not about the error message, but rather how to compare strings, just use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) (never use `==`, `eq`, or `isequal` to compare strings):

```
if strcmp(sortedCell{i},txt2(j))
    ...
end
```

I don't know what the `&& sortedCell{i}~=0` part you've added is for, but you can add it back if needed.

`strcmp` also take cell arrays as inputs (see the documentation) so you may be able to get rid of on of your `for` loops. I don't know what your code does, but maybe you you could use something like this:

```
for j=1:length(num2)
    c = strcmp(sortedCell,txt2(j));
    if any(c)
        rssi2sorted(c)=rssi2(j);
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. please go trough the question. I already done what you mention and is not working (end of the question)

Answer (score 0):

use strcmp (of strcmpi ignoring case) to test is strings are the same, isequal is for testing if values are numerically equal. e.g.

```
if ( strcmp(sortedCell{i},txt2(j)) && sortedCell(i)~=0 )
```